# Can this limit be found without using L'Hopital's Rule?

Tags: indeterminate-forms

$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{\sqrt[m]{x}-\sqrt[m]{a}}{x-a}$$

Can this limit be found without using L'Hopital's rule ?

Comment: Use the definition of the derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=a$. $$f'(a)=\lim\limits_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$$  Here $f(x)=\sqrt[m]{x}$. So the limit is $f'(a)=\frac{1}{m}a^{(1-m)/m}$.

Comment: It's the same as $$\lim_{y\to b}\frac{y-b}{y^n-b^n}$$ where $b=\sqrt[n]{y}$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For natural $m\geq2$ and $a>0$ we obtain:$$\frac{\sqrt[m]x-\sqrt[m]a}{x-a}=\tfrac{\sqrt[m]x-\sqrt[m]a}{(\sqrt[m]x-\sqrt[m]a)\left(\left(\sqrt[m]x\right)^{m-1}+\left(\sqrt[m]x\right)^{m-2}\sqrt[m]a+...+\sqrt[m]x\left(\sqrt[m]a\right)^{m-2}+\left(\sqrt[m]a\right)^{m-1}\right)}\rightarrow\frac{1}{m\sqrt[m]{a^{m-1}}}$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Set $y=\sqrt[m]{x}$, and $b=\sqrt[m]{a}$;

$\sqrt[m]{x}$ is a continuos function.

We can consider $\lim y \rightarrow b$,

$\lim_{y \rightarrow b}\dfrac{y-m}{y^m-b^m}$
(See Lord Shark's comment).

1) Set $y= b+h$ and let $\lim h \rightarrow 0$.

$F(h):=\dfrac{h}{(b+h)^m-b^m}$.

Binomial expansion of $(b+h)^m$, $m+1$ terms:

$(b+h)^m= b^m +mb^{m-1}h +O(h^2)$;

$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}F(h)=\dfrac{1}{mb^{m-1}}$.